Reason for the duplication of prepositions in Spanish?
Given the sentence "Al oso panda le encanta mascar hojas de bambú", why is the preposition "a" duplicated (once explicitly in "Al", once implicitly in "le")?
I see this sort of duplication a lot. Is there a way to rephrase this to eliminate the duplication, or is duplication of this sort a necessary linguistic feature of reflexive verbs in Spanish?

Hay una acción sistemática en las últimas respuestas con copy/paste de inteligencia artificial.
A todos los usuarios habituales de SpanishSE que suelen colaborar elaborando contenido, tened en cuenta y flaggead estas respuestas, es el único modo de mantener el sitio activo.

@Danielillo We should put this on META and ban AI here. Other sites do it, why shouldn't we?

There are already several posts on MetaSE, this is not something new. SE does not have a clear policy of action in this regard. The reason for my comment here is continuity, an AI-generated response can pass, it should be credited. But when it is systematic, the problem is different. At the moment the action is flagging these answers.


Al oso panda le encanta mascar hojas de bambú.

What there is is duplication of the indirect object, which is necessary with verbs like "encantar", as explained here:

La duplicación del complemento indirecto posverbal mediante el clítico es normalmente opcional, aunque suele ser lo más frecuente, cuando se trata de complementos directos argumentales (exigidos por el verbo): verbos que expresan un proceso de transmisión de algo a un destinatario, o indican transmisión de mensaje o de un conocimiento.


La duplicación es necesaria con los verbos que expresan beneficios o perjuicios, posesión o parte inalienable, así como con los verbos gustar, encantar y sinónimos; suele ser necesaria en los verbos cuyo complemento indirecto designa, no al destinatario de la acción, sino al que la experimenta: verbos de afección psíquica o física, como molestar, divertir, interesar, cansar, etc. y otros como parecer, resultar, convenir, etc.


Cuando la función de complemento indirecto es desempeñada por los cuantificadores universales todo, nadie o similares, la presencia del pronombre átono no resulta siempre necesaria.

To make it clearer, there are certain verbs (usually expressing transfer of something) that may take the "a"-indirect object (IO) without the need to duplicate the IO with the pronoun "le" or "les", while with other verbs (as is the case with "encantar" and the verbs mentioned in the quote above) the duplicate prononominal IO will be required:

El cuidador da hojas de bambú al oso panda. (Here "le" is optional: El cuidador (le) da hojas de bambú al oso panda.).

El turista (le) ofrece hojas de bambú al oso panda.

El dueño de la plantación (le) envía hojas de bambú al oso panda.


With the other verbs mentioned above, "le" is required:

Las hojas de bambú le gustan/le encantan al oso panda.

Las hojas de bambú le parecen deliciosas al oso panda.

Comer siempre lo mismo no le molesta al oso panda.



I doubt a person learning Spanish will understand those citations, especially without explaining the explanation with the preposition a.

the verb encantar and gustar work like this:
algo [noun or pronoun: el helado, for  instance] le gusta a alguien [una persona].
algo [noun or pronoun: el helado, for  instance] le encanta a alguien [una persona].

El helado le encanta a Maria.
Los libros me gustan a mi.

Due to the prepositional phrase a plus  noun or pronoun, you get:
object + indirect  object (le, les, nosotros, etc.) + verb ( singular or plural depending on the direct object] + a + pronoun or noun.
OR You can start with indirect object or even the main verb:

A mi me gusta el helado.
El helado me gusta a mi.
Me gusta a mi el helado.

The main point is THIS: a alguien le gusta algo
A nosotros nos gustan estas manzanas**. OR
Nos gustan a nosotros estas manzanas.  [or nos gustan at the end]
The verb has to agree in number (singular or plural with the direct object).

Mal la estructura propuesta; se comienza por el objeto indirecto, no por el sujeto. Ninguno de tus dos ejemplos reflejan tu estructura en ningún momento.

@tac No es verdad: Se puede perfectamente empezar con el sujeto.

But why is this necessary? "me" and "a mí" mean the same thing.

I told you: gustarse a alguien.  You have to have me gusta, the a mi is an emphatic as in: I do like books. One is part of the reflexive verb and the other emphasizes to whom the thing is pleasing (who likes it). Call it an intensifier.

@LukeHutchison They don't have the same function in the sentence. See my previous comment. :)

In Spanish, the duplication you’re noticing is a common feature and not necessarily tied to reflexive verbs.   Let’s break it down:

“Al oso panda”: This is a contraction of “a el oso panda,” where “a” is a preposition used to indicate the indirect object (the panda bear in this case).
“Le encanta”: Here, “le” is an indirect object pronoun that also refers to the panda bear.
The use of both “a” and “le” is a way to emphasize and clarify the indirect object. This is known as redundant object pronoun usage and is quite common in Spanish.

Rephrasing to Eliminate Duplication
While this redundancy is grammatically correct and often used for clarity, you can rephrase the sentence to avoid it. For example:
•   “El oso panda disfruta mascar hojas de bambú.”
Here, “disfruta” (enjoys) is used instead of “le encanta” (loves), eliminating the need for the indirect object pronoun.
However, keep in mind that the original sentence with the redundancy is perfectly natural and commonly used in Spanish.

Respuesta copiada de ChatGPT

It is not duplication at all. It's the grammar for that structure.
